# moment.js: format a date keeping the locale's day, month and year order

Tags: javascript, date, format, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to format some dates in a "country specific" order, using the native [locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) feature. So, for example, this code will print a date ordered in the Netherlands's default:

```
moment.locale('nl');
nlDate = moment();
nlDate.format('ll'); // "12 nov. 2014"
```

A different locale setting will print a different order:

```
moment.locale('en');
nlDate = moment();
nlDate.format('ll'); // "Nov 12, 2014"
```

What I would like to do is to change the format of the output string, keeping the locale order; so for example:

```
(nl) 12 nov. 2014   -->   12-11-'14
(en) Nov 12, 2014   -->   11-12-'14
```

Sadly, by a custom [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), I am not able to keep the locale order:

```
nlDate = moment();

nlDate.locale('nl');
nlDate.format("DD-MM-'YY"); // "12-11-'14"

nlDate.locale('en');
nlDate.format("DD-MM-'YY"); // "12-11-'14"
```

From the above I would like to get:

```
(nl) 11-12-'14
(en) 12-11-'14
```

Any help?

I am addressing my effort [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) and [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) but not sure I am in the right direction.

Thank you,
Luca

Comment: Just to let you know en order is DD/MM/YYYY, well in the UK anyway. US have it backwards and put MM first.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
moment.locale("nl").format('L');
```

and

```
moment.locale("en").format('L');
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't let me specify a custom format string!

Answer (score 0):

Customize the language settings seems to work pretty well:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LT: "h:mm A",
        L: "MM-DD-'YY",
        LL: "MMMM Do YYYY",
        LLL: "MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        LLLL: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT"
    }
});
moment.locale("en");
moment().format("L"); // 11-12-'14
```

So far is the best I have found and I am pretty happy with it.

Comment: MomentJs says it's deprecated, and recommends updateLocale instead.